# ng-checked In angular 1.6 not forcing a checkbox to remain unchecked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a input element wired up to a function `IsChecked`. `IsChecked` always returns false, I expect that checkbox to never be checked regardless of how many clicks it recieves. What is happening instead is the checkbox is changing to checked and un-checked irregardless of my function.

How can I force a checkbox to remain unchecked based off of a function call?

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>Hello {{ user.firstName }}</div>
    <input ng-model="user.firstName"></input>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login"></input>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="IsChecked()"></input>
    <div ng-repeat="login in logins">{{ login }}</div>
    <div>{{IsChecked()}}</div>
</div>
```

```js
function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        firstName: "Foo",
        lastName: "Bar"
    };
    $scope.logins = [];
    $scope.IsChecked =function(){
        return false;
    }
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.logins.push($scope.user.firstName + " was logged in.");
    };
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wr0cqmnk/)

Comment: How you use that checkbox?

Comment: Because it doesn't "force" the checkbox to stay unchecked, just indicate whether it's checked or not. You could do something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/fu37myg8/) to force a checkbox to be unchecked

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend my alternative above, I would prefer to disable the checkbox using `ngDisabled` instead

Comment: The Fiddle is flagging HTML errors. The `<input>` element is a void element. The closing tag `</input>` is erroneous. Just use the `ng-disabled` directive to have the element ignore clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `ng-model` on that checkbox and associate a `on-click` function so that whenever you click on the checkbox the function will revert it back to unchecked.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
  <div>Hello {{ user.firstName }}</div>
  <input ng-model="user.firstName"></input>
  <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login"></input>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxCheck"
         ng-click="CheckStatus()"></input>
  <div ng-repeat="login in logins">{{ login }}</div>
  <div>{{checkboxCheck}}</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function LoginController($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    firstName: "Foo",
    lastName: "Bar"
  };
  $scope.logins = [];
  $scope.checkboxCheck = false;
  $scope.IsChecked = function() {
    $scope.checkboxCheck = false;
    return $scope.checkboxCheck;
  }
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.logins.push($scope.user.firstName + " was logged in.");
  };
  $scope.CheckStatus = function() {
    $scope.checkboxCheck = false;
  }
}
```

Here is the working example in [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/74g1ahLd/)

Comment: The `ng-checked` and `ng-model` directive should not be used together. `ng-checked` is for two-way binding; `ng-checked`, one-way binding.

Comment: @georgeawg I updated the answer. Thanks for suggestion. Does it still need downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-checked` directive sets the checked attribute of a `checkbox` or a `radiobutton`.

The checkbox, or radiobutton, will be checked if the expression inside the ng-checked attribute returns true.

But that is only for setting it unchecked in beginning, next time when you click on it, you set the checked attribute to true.

You should bind a `ng-model` to the checkbox and set it to false always. 
Or just keep the checkbox disabled by adding attribute `ngDisabled` to it so that it's not checked. EX:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="isChecked" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the change event using `ng-change` and pass a model to read the checkbox's value using `ng-model`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="CheckedChanged()" ng-model="isChecked" />
```

And to make it remain unchecked -

```
$scope.CheckedChanged =function(){
    $scope.isChecked = false; // To make it remain unchecked
}
```

Check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cydr6szw/2/)

In this way you can omit `ng-checked` in that case. `ng-checked` and `ng-model` are not meant to be used together. A use case for using `ng-checked` can be when, let's say you're creating a checkbox dynamically and you need to pass an expression to set the state of the checkbox.